# Proof check - equivalence classes are intervals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

We define $\sim$ for a nonempty subset $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ by: $x\sim y$ if $\lbrack\min\lbrace x,y\rbrace,\max\lbrace x,y\rbrace\rbrack\subseteq X.$ This is an equivalence relation on $X.$ I want to show that any equivalence class $E$ is an interval. If $X=\mathbb{R}$ then it seems obvious that $\mathbb{R}$ is the only equivalence class so I stick with $X\neq\mathbb{R}.$ Here is my attempt at proof.

Take any $a,b\in E;$ choose $a<b.$ If $\lbrack a,b\rbrack\not\subseteq E$ then there is $c\in\lbrack a,b\rbrack$ with $c\not\in E.$ But $\lbrack a,c\rbrack\cup\lbrack c,b\rbrack=\lbrack a,b\rbrack\subseteq X$ which contradicts $c\not\in E.$ And a definition of an interval is given $a,b\in X$ that $\lbrack a,b\rbrack\subseteq X.$ So $E$ is an interval.

This seems too quick, and I didn't need to consider the case that $X$ is unbounded, bounded, etc., but I don't see a problem with the proof. Can someone tell me if I have made a mistake somewhere?

Also, this is a homework question, so please don't post the whole answer, just a yes or no with reasons why is enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According that you look this relation on $X$ (which is necessary to have equivalence classes), your proof seems correct. In fact, the equivalence classes are the connected composants of $X$, id est the "part without holes" of $X$.

You can see that this is the best way to write $X= \bigcup_{i\in I} |a_i, b_i|$ where this intervals are disjoints.

In some cases, this partition can be trivial (look for example, when $X=\mathbb Q$, or $\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, or even the triadic Cantor compact).

If you want to look forward : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components